# Value only being set to the first word in the sentence

Tags: php, html, laravel, select, get

I'm trying to make a select box using laravel, and I can't figure out why the value is only being set to the first word in the sentence.
I've tried all the following variations with no success. The full sentence gets printed fine in the box, it's just the value that gets posted doesn't.

```
 @foreach($sentences as $sentence)
 <option value = "{!!$sentence!!}">{{$sentence}}</option>
 @endforeach

@foreach($sentences as $sentence)
 <option value = "{{$sentence}}">{{$sentence}}</option>
 @endforeach

@foreach($sentences as $sentence)
 <option value = '{{$sentence}}'>{{$sentence}}</option>
 @endforeach
```

I can't seem to find the proper documentation that would explain this.

Comment: could you edit your question and put your expected output and can you also show us the value of `$sentences` by dumping it?

Comment: I figured it out. the problem wasnt here, I was using $result->get() as opposed to ->input